# Chrome continuously blocking microphone from IBM websphere server

Tags: javascript, java, html, google-chrome, websphere

I am working in Java environment, I am trying to access microphone through my EAR which is deployed on IBM websphere server but unable to access it because chrome continuously blocking microphone.

When I am trying to access a local file which is located at C:\Users\abcd\Desktop\index.html and double click on it, it ran successfully chrome asks for permission and microphone works properly.

But the same file when I am deploying on IBM websphere server and trying to access it, chrome continuously blocking microphone instead of asking for permission.

I have gone through all the stackoverflow solutions, but none of them worked.Is there any workaround or solution so that I can forcefully allows microphone in chrome while accessing my websphere server url, struggling on it, any kind of help will be appreciated.

```
Note : 

IBM Websphere version : 8.5

Chrome version        : 68
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably not a server-side issue.

- Have you clicked on "Disallow access" *and* "Don't ask again" ?
- In that case try to change the URL and/or the server name and/or port, then test again

The microphone API access is granted [per-origin](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/#dom-mediadevices-getusermedia), see steps 9.4. - there are no reasons it stays denied if you cleared the denial list (unless you're serving non-HTTPS, I can't remember if `getUserMedia()` constrains the transport layer security)